# Generating 'customers also bought' from table

Tags: php, mysql

I've got a 'cart' table as follows:

```
+----+---------+-----------+----------+----------+
| id | orderID | productID | quantity |  status  |
+----+---------+-----------+----------+----------+
|  1 |    3443 |       333 |        2 | complete |
|  2 |    3443 |       202 |        4 | complete |
+----+---------+-----------+----------+----------+
```

And so foreach order, a new row gets added for each item in the cart.

So I want to get an 'customers also bought' from this table.  I'm using MySQL.

How can I do this? This is what I came up with at first:

```
SELECT * FROM `cart` WHERE `status` = 'complete' AND `productID` = '333' ORDER BY `ts` DESC
```

But of course this only shows me the the rows with that productID in.  What I really want is the *other* products of orders that *contain* that productID.

How can I go about doing this?

Comment: there isnt anny customerID in the table

Comment: No, I dont care about customer ID, I just want to find other products that people have in the same order.  So in this case, I want to end up with the productID `202`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably do this with a self-join on the `cart` table:

```
Select Distinct mapped.productID
  From cart main
  Join cart mapped On main.orderID = mapped.orderID
 Where main.productID != mapped.productID
   And main.productID = 333
```

Answer (score 1):

There are already two correct answers.  I'm just trying to give you an idea about the order (or the importance) of productID you show.
You could for example use a query like this, using the number of times a certain productID was bought (other than 'ts'):

```
SELECT `productID`, COUNT(*) AS RC
FROM `cart` 
WHERE `orderID` IN (SELECT `orderID` FROM `cart` WHERE `productid`=333 AND `status` = 'complete' )                      
AND `productID` <> '333' 
GROUP BY  `productID`
ORDER BY RC DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Use could make use off a IN filter like this.

```
   SELECT
     productID
    FROM 
     cart
    WHERE
       orderID IN(
         SELECT   
          orderId 
         FROM
          cart
         WHERE
            productID = 333
          AND
            status = 'complete'
       )
     AND
       productID <> 333
     AND
       status = 'complete'
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want the products in the same order then you can query by `orderID`, e.g.:

```
SELECT * 
FROM cart
WHERE orderID = 3443
AND productID <> 333;
```

This will give you all the `other` products that were included in the same order.

Comment: Okay, but when the table 90,000 rows, how is that going to help me? I'm not interested in order numbers.

Comment: What other numbers? Regardless of how many rows are there in the table, this query will return only those products which were included in order id `3443`.